# Using a string as an operator?

Tags: python, operators, performance, repeat

For example, let's say I have a bunch of assignment statements like this:

```
if operator == '==':
   if a == b:
       c += 5
elif operator == '>':
   if a > b:
       c += 5
elif operator == '<':
   if a < b:
       c += 5
```

The if nested if statements and assignments I gave are just examples but in the program I'm writing, they are really long. Just a small change is present where the operators differ, so I don't want to have to repeat the same long piece of code over and over again just for all these conditions. There are too many conditions and the code will get repeated many times..so is there a "faster" way to do this? Can I maybe define a string as an operator? Or any better ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
from operator import *

str_ops = {'<':lt,'>':gt,'==':eq} # etc
op = str_ops.get(my_operator) #where my_operator was previously your 'operator'
assert op is not None #or raise your own exception
if op(a,b):
    c+=5
```

And, if you wanted to gracefully handle a bogus operator in `my_operator`, you can do:

```
op = str_ops.get(my_operator, lambda x,y: None) #fallback: do-nothing operator
```

Bonuses to this approach:

- ONE `if` statement.  No matter how many operators you're handling.
- O(1) behavior, as opposed to O(n) with branching if/elif statements.
- The `dict` is very declarative: *this* string goes to *this* operator.
- Doesn't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: +1 Nice one :), you might wanna handle non existent case as well.

Comment: By `operators` you mean `str_ops` right? In that case, you dont need lambda to return `None`. You can simply say `None`

Comment: @thefourtheye well, `None` is the default fall-back from `.get`, so I wouldn't need to specify that.  And I do need a `lambda` there, since `None(a,b)` doesn't work out so well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `and` and `or` operators effectively, like this

```
if (operator == '==' and a == b) or (operator == '>' and a > b) \
      or (operator == '<' and a < b):
    c += 5
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution, if you can trust the source of the operator string (or have some way of validating it) you can use `eval`. But you have to be really careful when using `eval`; it can be a big security risk if you don't trust the source of the input.

```
if eval("a %s b" % operator):
    c += 5
```